# I messed up in my master branch in git, created a new branch, how to make this branch new master?

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

So basically it looks like this:

[image]

I want to discard the commit called, but it is in master branch:

```
6e228be
Main.storyboard screen fix.
```

And make the Xcode7 branch new master, or merge without the above commit. How do I do it ?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to checkout master and reset off the tip commit, then fast forward merge the xcode7 branch.

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard HEAD~
git merge Xcode7
```